# Create a command that centers output in its cell

Tags: output-formatting

How would I create a command,`Centering`, which would center output within the cell in which it is displayed. For example, I would like

```
 Plot[x^2, {x, 0,1}] // Centering
```

to center the plotin the cell resulting from its evaluation.

Comment: Ok Corey979,  my question is not far from the suggested one but what I do not understand clearly is how to  transform the answers in suhc a way to use it as I suggest --- since parameters must be added

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that what I was expecting is this

```
centering := CellPrint[ExpressionCell[#, "Output", TextAlignment -> Center]] &
```

and

```
 Plot[x^2,{i, 1, 10}]// centering
```